# Simplify .setFormula code in Google Apps Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code in google sheets and I want to make it more efficient, simplify the code.

It goes without saying I'm new to the code.

```
function onEdit(e){

  if(e.range.getA1Notation() != "A3") return;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("screen");
  var cell1 = sheet.getRange("D1:D3");
  var cell2 = sheet.getRange("j1:j3");
  var cell3 = sheet.getRange("o1:o3");
  var cell4 = sheet.getRange("r1:r3");
  var cell5 = sheet.getRange("t1:t3");
  var cell6 = sheet.getRange("w1:w3");
  var cell7 = sheet.getRange("z1:z3");
  var cell8 = sheet.getRange("ac1:ac3");
  var cell9 = sheet.getRange("ag1:ag3");
  var cell10 = sheet.getRange("a3");

 cell1.setFormula('="Any"');
 cell2.setFormula('="Any"');
 cell3.setFormula('="Any"');
 cell4.setFormula('="Any"');
 cell5.setFormula('="Any"');
 cell5.setFormula('="Any"');
 cell6.setFormula('="Any"');
 cell7.setFormula('="Any"');
 cell8.setFormula('="Any"');
 cell9.setFormula('="Any"');
 cell10.clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to simplify the script.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, it seems that the formula for putting to ranges is the same. I thought that this will be useful for your goal.
- And, in your situation, I think that the event object can be used. When the event object is used, the process cost can be reduced. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546)

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  if(range.getA1Notation() != "A3") return;
  const a1Notations = ["D1:D3", "j1:j3", "o1:o3", "r1:r3", "t1:t3", "w1:w3", "z1:z3", "ac1:ac3", "ag1:ag3"];
  e.source.getSheetByName("screen").getRangeList(a1Notations).setFormula('="Any"');
  range.clearContent();
}
```

- In this case, `setFormula` of Class RangeList is used for putting the formula. And, using the event object, the range is used for `clearContent`.

  - By this modification, I think that the process cost of the script can be also reduced.

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Benchmark: Event Objects for Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546)
- [setFormula(formula) of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setFormula(String))